# Understanding Resolution and Aspect Ratio

Tags: resolution

i want that 4:3 resolution. but no matter what i try only 640x480 gives me that. trying any other 4:3 ratio shows my video in a black box.
1024x768
1280x960
aso

from my understanding: putting the same values into video editor render like i rendered those png files should do the job.

also tried different settings for the aspect x/y but same problem there, no matter what value the black box still present.

when rendering the png files everything looks perfect. then i put those files into the video editor and i get this.

[image]

are there aspect ratio or resolution data stored inside keyframes?
i recorded those keyframes while using 640x480 but for rendering the png files later on i tried 1024✕768 for better quality. could this cause my problem?

those were my initial settings:

[image]

[image]

after that i tried different setting in video editors aspect x/y. (ignore the fps settings, it were always set to the same amount like the png files)

this is how it always gets rendered.

[image]

just figured out: when i put 640x480 into the video editor render i get the full size without black borders. this makes no sense because i rendered the png files in (for example) 1280x960.

found the problem. looks like i rendered all the frames in 640x480 no matter the values. just checked all the files, my high quality stuff had the same file size like the 480p stuff. i probably bugged my instance - typing in higher values does no change.

sorry for non-problem.

Comment: Could you add screenshots or upload your file with https://blend-exchange.com/ ? No, the resolution of the output is unique for each *Scene*. We would need more informations to understand what's wrong.

Comment: You have Pixel Aspect X set to 11 and Y to 12 in the output settings. Why? This is pixel aspect ratio. This is if you need to output your renders for devices with non-square pixels. Are you using any such devices with pixel aspect ratio of 11:12?

Comment: Also, looks like your 2 screenshots of Blender are from different scenes (not same FPS, nor same frame start or end).

Comment: yes i tried all the different settings in video editor while having the scene still on it's defaults - sorry for the confusion. i usually have multiple instances open.

the problem was i was expecting blender to use the filenames as reference. so when i rendered frame 3000 -3100 and later on in video editor tried to render them, i put in those numbers instead of 0-100. so i rendered my 480p stuff over and over without noticing (for 3 days straight, hahahaha) that's what you got for doing backrooms. every frame looks the same. sorry again.

Comment: Don't change the pixel aspect ratio. Just set a resolution of whatever ratio you want. You can easily find lists of common resolutions of any ratio online. Example: https://www.videoproc.com/video-process/4-3-resolutions.htm